# liboverride_troubleshoot_operation() proper context sought

Tags: python, linked-data

If I try to invoke the `bpy.ops.outliner.liboverride_troubleshoot_operation(...)` from a script I get an improper context error, although I've set_select(True) the armature that is linked.

I'm wondering if that is because *troubleshoot* is trying to verify that it is being invoked from the outliner, making it impossible to call from a script?

I am trying to call this from a script, because I have a linked armature that *always* has misplaced bones when the blend file is loaded, making it impossible to render from command line without the re-sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a [bug report](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/110113) and was given the following code that works:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen

    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            with context.temp_override(window=window, area=area):
                bpy.ops.outliner.liboverride_troubleshoot_operation( type='OVERRIDE_LIBRARY_RESYNC_HIERARCHY', selection_set='SELECTED')
            break;
```